# Complexity of a code fragment part2

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Give the complexity of the following code fragment in terms of the input size
N:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // n*
    for(int j =1;j<=n;j=j*2) // n/2 (its half n, but I assume it still counts as n, or is it log(n)?)
        a[i]=a[j-1]/2; // 1

for(int i=0;i-n;i++) // n*
    if(a[i] %2==0)  // 1*
        a[i]=2*a[i]; // 1
```

You start from the bottom up.
Is complexity: n^2 + n so is it O(n^2)?

Is there anywhere I can learn about how to compute complexities of simple algorithms?

Comment: We can help you more if you show us how far you have got with your answer.

Comment: I did. Below the code the formula and in comments too: //n stands for the complexity I think that this line holds. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you doubted,

`for(int j =1;j<=n;j=j*2)`

this is O(logn), since every iteration j is multiplied by 2. So the total time is O(nlogn).

And as for where to look at, I love Introduction to Algorithms, but any good textbook would suffice if only for the simple algorithms' analysis.